# I'm having an issue with an error that I'm getting with my "else if" statement.

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

It seems this error happens a lot on certain computers when dealing with if/else if, because sometimes I'll have absolutely no problems with implementing this (not implementing Thread t = new Thread(this);, haha...), and sometimes Eclipse will shoot the error message: "Syntax error on token "else", { expected."

Here's the snippet:

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    char keyLetter = e.getKeyChar();
    if(Character.*isLetterOrDigit*(keyLetter));

}
else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
    dis.setWaitingforInputfalse();
}
}
}
```

If I actually put in the curly brace like it wants me to in that ridiculous spot,
Ex:

```
else{ if(keyCode etc.etc.etc){
}
```

then it throws the error:

Multiple markers at this line
- keyCode cannot be resolved to a variable
- Syntax error on token "else", delete this token

Will tossing in "private int keyCode;" up at the top fix it, or is that just going to cause some issues later on down the road for making it a function instead of a variable or something?

And should I leave it as

```
{ if(keyCode etc.){
}
```

Or is there a way to get the else if statement to work? Because any form of trying to add in else just throws back an error.

Comment: Check your brackets — your `else if` bloxk is outside the `keyTyped` method.

Comment: Are you in an intro to computer science class and asking help for your homework?  :D

Comment: Hint: if you put the cursor before or after a `{` or `}`, Eclipse will draw a rectangle around its mate.

Comment: But, seriously, the problem is straight-forward.  You're using a semi-colon when you should be using a left curly brace.  You've either completely missed this or you're not really familiar with how to use curly braces.

Comment: It's a simple typo.  Although not everyone will admit it, I'm sure most of us here have made subtle mistakes like this and stared at them until we went cross-eyed.

Answer (score 5):

You have a few issues in your code:

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    char keyLetter = e.getKeyChar();
    if(Character.*isLetterOrDigit*(keyLetter)); // The if statement ends here 
                                                // because of the ;

} // the function keyTyped ends here
else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){ // the else is not connected to the if
    dis.setWaitingforInputfalse();
}
}
}
```

You need a `{`  instead of a `;` behind the if.

Answer (score 2):

Because you mistakenly put `;` after your `if` statement instead of `{`, you're inadvertently closing the keyTyped method prematurely.  As a result, the `else` is disconnected from any `if` statement (which is not allowed in Java) and your `keyCode` variable is out of scope.

After your `if` statement, replace the `;` with a `{`.  It also looks like you have a stray `}` at the end.  In the code below, I also removed the extraneous `*`'s from the `if` condition.

Fixed code:

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    char keyLetter = e.getKeyChar();
    if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(keyLetter)) {
        // do something
    }
    else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        dis.setWaitingforInputfalse();
    }
}
```

Hint: in most IDEs and code editors (including Eclipse), if you position the (typing) cursor on a `(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, `{`, or `}`, then the editor will highlight or draw a rectangle around its mate.

Answer (score 1):

hats because you are closing the keyTyped method before else so you need to remove the closing brace before 'else' and also add the statements for 'if' part -

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
 int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
 char keyLetter = e.getKeyChar();
 if(Character.*isLetterOrDigit*(keyLetter)){
 //do something here
 }
 else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
   dis.setWaitingforInputfalse();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You  don't seem to have the opening {. After if you have just ; which should be ok but it doesn't expect closing brace.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 4 opening braces {, you also should have 4 closing ones }

So when you type the code, simply put {} both opening and closing braces immediately, then step back inside this block and continue typing inside there. This way you will never lose braces.